# Is there a way to get a WAN IP address from a phone based on its phone number?

Tags: java, android, p2p, file-transfer

I would like to connect two phones together for somewhat of a P2P style connection and naturally to do so, I need the phones to be able to communicate their IP addresses to each other. I've been playing around with a lot of ideas on how to do this and one thing I realized is that a phone number is a unique identifier for a phone and thus I was wondering if it could be used to get IP addresses.

I think I could transmit certain messages over SMS that would be encrypted, look god-awful, and then get deleted, but that would be a bit of a hack and a terribly messy way to do things. I'm still mostly planning for this area of my project and would be open to suggestions.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you ahead of time! :0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a dynamic DNS service, using the phone number as the hostname. In other words, you would simply do a DNS lookup of e.g. `4255551212.dyndns.com` and you'd get the last known IP address of the given phone number.

The dynamic DNS service was invented to let people on dial-up (or with frequently-changing IP addresses) run servers on their computers with host names that did not change. The way it works is, there's a client on the computer that periodically reports its IP address to a server, which puts it in a zone file on a DNS server under the specified host name.  The DNS record has a short time-to-live (e.g. a minute) so that stale address information is not cached.

There's a dynamic DNS client for Android, look for DynDNS in the market and try it out.

You could run your own dynamic DNS server or use an existing one (there are many, some free). If you do do this, I would suggest running your own; then you could include some kind of authentication to prevent the privacy issue I mention in a comment.

Comment: *sigh* Excuse my ignorance, but I'm a little new to networking. Could you explain to me what that means?

Comment: If we have verified this will work, any chance I could get a link to an example and/or maybe a brief explanation? So I can either see that this is the answer or refine my question?

Comment: I just happened to think about privacy implications of this idea. If someone knows your phone number, they can get your IP address. They can then get your (very) approximate location, which might be enough to tell them if you're away from home. Probably not the best solution. I'm going try to write another answer.

Comment: Right now my application is for some in-house stuff and I also plan to encrypt plenty and need a special request key or something. It may not be air-tight, but I swear its more secure than first glance. 

Also, I may not fully understand some things. Is there something I should know about dynamic DNS servicing that makes this an awful idea?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure if this is what I was looking for, but it definitely answers my question sufficiently. Thank you for your help, I may be working on both figuring this out and/or coming up with a better question.

Answer (score 1):

A problem you will find is that 3G/cell connectivity gives no IP address.  Also, if your phone is behind a router, you would have to port-forward on the router to get a P2P connection (without a central server being involved).

That said, if you want the external IP address, it seems that hitting http://www.whatsmyip.org/ is the best way to go.

Note: I do not know much about the dynamic DNS option suggested by kindall.

Comment: Thanks, like I said, any help is appreciated. I was unaware that 3G didn't give IP addresses... yikes... thanks though.

Comment: That makes sense, I guess 3G Internet traffic has to go through the carrier's gateway. You will have a visible IP address, but it'll be a proxy used by lots of people, and not allow inbound traffic. As for the WiFi router, you can potentially get an inbound connection using STUN, UP&P, etc. but that adds a lot of complexity.

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure you cannot directly do so. I think you need both phones to transfer phonenumber and IP to your own server and tie everything together through there. Privacy issues will creep up whatever solution you choose though, when phonenumber is involved.

Also I don't know whether you actually can connect from phone A to B directly even IF you have the IP number? But I am not an App Dev yet, so you probably know better if you can set up an end-point / open socket like thing at phone B.

Comment: Thanks for insight. I've heard that protocol might be blocked, so the connection problems isn't to surprising, but I know some things use P2P as an option so I'm fairly confident I can find a way around it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a site like www.whatsmyip.org to get you ip address

it is possible that your phone shares its  ip address with other clients

you could also use a vpn or depending on your application a mediator server using soup or xmpp